# Lower bound for the size of prime factors?

Tags: elliptic-curves, factoring, multi-prime-rsa

We all know classic RSA and that we should pick moduli of at least 2048-bit length to get decent (112 bit) security.

Now there's also multi-prime RSA, [which can yield significant speed-ups](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/11288/23623) using the Chinese Remainder Theorem (CRT).

However, the security considerations for this aren't well-known to most people, so I'm asking here:
**Given a security level of n-bits, what's the minimal size the factors of a modulus need to have in order to achieve that level?**

Please note, that side-channel attacks and similar attacks on bad choices of the primes should not be exploited here.

If it's not possible to give a generic strategy for all security levels, concrete numbers for $n\in\{112,128,192,256\}$ should be included.

As for my own research, I realize that the [ECM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenstra_elliptic_curve_factorization) is the best method at factoring and that it has a similar run-time behavior to the quadratic sieve, but actual numbers and security estimates are sparse and that's what I'm interested in.

Comment: Related [question](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/15823/555)

Comment: The second answer there from D.W. has a nice table. Note that I *feel* something is not entirely right with regards to the rapid increase of the number of primes in time, I'd stick to the year 2001 predictions.