# In RSA, given $n=100$ and $e=13$ ,Encrypt and Decrypt the plain Text "SECRET"

Tags: rsa

Is this question valid as $n=100$ is not a product of two primes, but can be expressed as $100=2^2 5^2$, if valid is there any criteria for choosing $d$  and other values?

Comment: Welcome to Cryptography. Is this homework question? What you see is [multi-prime key RSA](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/11287/rsa-with-modulus-product-of-many-primes).**Hint:** $n$ is already a composite, therefore, same rules apply. You need to find $\varphi(n=100)$ and then you can find $d$.

Comment: @kelalaka: what you propose won't work.

Comment: @fgrieu well, I think it is not about the functionality it is about security, right?

Comment: @kelalaka: problem is, in RSA, when the modulus is not [squarefree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-free_integer), some plaintexts encrypt to the same ciphertext. Here, for all standard alphabets, that will prevent decryption.

Comment: @kelalaka, yes I found φ(n=100) as 40 and found d as 37.And as fgrieu stated , the encrypted text is not decrypted to same plain text if the values of letters has common factors with n=100, i.e when letter  e=5 is used , it is not decrypted to letter e. But letter e=some other number with no common factors with 100, such as 7,11,13,19 .. is used ,this works. this question is not about security .I have to encrypt and decrypt . Is that possible?

Comment: Well, it really depends. your plaintext is larger than modulus size. You have to use some correct encoding decoding otherwise as fgrieu said, some decryption will fail. What is the point of the question? Use standard RSA or at least use a square free multi-prime RSA?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least, there's an issue with using $n=100$ as the public modulus in RSA: that number is not [squarefree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-free_integer). This implies that $m\mapsto m^e\bmod n$ can't be a bijection of the range $[0,n)$. And thus we must restrict the plaintext space to something lesser than $[0,n)$ if we want a deterministic decryption procedure.

Proof: if $n$ is not squarefree, there exists $s>1$ with $s^2$ dividing $n$. Let $m$ be an element of the subset $\mathcal S$ of $[0,n)$ with multiples of $s$. For $e>2$, $m^e$ is a multiple of $s^2$, which divides $n$. Therefore $s^2$ divides $m^e\bmod n$. Therefore $m^e\bmod n$ belongs to the subset $\mathcal T$ of $[0,n)$ with multiples of $s^2$. $|\mathcal S|=n/s$ and $|\mathcal T|=n/s^2$. Thus $|\mathcal S|>|\mathcal T|$. Therefore the function $f:\mathcal S\to\mathcal T, m\mapsto m^e\bmod n$ is bound to collide. Such collision is also a collision for RSA encryption on $[0,n)$.

For example, with $n=100$ and $e=13$, $m_A=65$ and $m_U=85$ both encipher to $25$. This means we can't even reversibly encipher the uppercase ASCII alphabet. If we try to use $c\mapsto c^d\bmod n$ for $d=e^{-1}\bmod\varphi(n)$ as a decryption function, it will sometime fail. For example, $m_R=82$ enciphers to $c=32$ and deciphers to $32\ne m_R$.

Comment: so can I use An encoding such that the values of letters and n (here 100) has no common factors>1 @fgrieu

Comment: @sumar: indeed, that will work. In fact, it is enough to restrict to messages $m=0$ or $m\in[1,n)$ such that $m$ and $n$ have no common factor which square divides $n$. For $n=300$ that allows $m$ to be $0$, $3$, $9$, $21$, $27$, $33$..